# Nextcloud 12: blank page after downgrade from php 7.2

Tags: php, apache2, arch-linux, php7, nextcloud

my Arch Linux machine running Nextcloud on a LAMP-Stack got updates for `php 7.2.0` a few days ago. Unfortunately, Nextcloud does not support `php 7.2.0`, and [won't do so until the next major release](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/7384). So I had to downgrade my `php 7.2.0`-packages back to `php 7.1.12`.

Unfortunately, when opening my nextcloud page in the browser, there's only a blank page visible containing nothing. The apache error logs don't show any errors:

```
[Fri Dec 08 00:03:49.841065 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 486] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.1.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 08 00:03:49.872712 2017] [core:notice] [pid 486] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

The access log shows `[08/Dec/2017:00:37:25 +0100] "GET /nextcloud/status.php HTTP/1.1" 500 -`. When I upgrade the packages to `php 7.2.0`, I get the Nextcloud error page:

```
This version of Nextcloud is not compatible with PHP 7.2.
You are currently running 7.2.0.
```

So the webserver seems to be configured correctly. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check your php.ini and make sure you haven't suppressed error logging somehow. Then try again.

Comment: In `php.ini`, `log_errors = On`. Anything else to check?

Comment: Check where the errors are being logged.

Comment: The default value, I guess the apache error log. I think, I have already seen some php errors in there. Furthermore, `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` are on. I've also specified a log file location for testing purposes, and tested by using `log_error()` if an error gets logged there, and yes it does - but no still no nextcloud errors appear.